# Can I restrict Azure API Management cache storage by response content?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-caching

I have an OLTP API where a client can check for the status of a transaction.

Often, clients make multiple status requests for a transactions which are in a final state e.g. cancelled. I'd like to leverage Azure API Management response caching but **ONLY** for responses where the transaction status was final.

The API response body message is simply URL encoded e.g. `reference=ABC123&status=Cancelled&amount=123.45` so determining if the transaction status is final should be simple

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @MohamadHaidar answer, I was able to construct a policy to achieve the caching, however the response body is now blank! I suspect this is because its being read by the condition and its only able to be read once?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(Regex.IsMatch(context.Response.Body.As<string>(), @"status=(Cancelled|Paid)"))">
                <cache-store duration="3600" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [@MohamadHaidar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719009/175893), I was able to construct my solution which I have shared below.

**NOTE:** One needs to set `preserveContent: true` when reading the request/response body (unless you're going to set your own body after having read the existing one) otherwise it will no longer be available in the pipeline. More on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#example-accessing-the-body-as-a-string-note-that-we-are-preserving-the-original-request-body-so-that-we-can-access-it-later-in-the-pipeline)

So, the final solution was per below:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(Regex.IsMatch(context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true), @"status=(Cancelled|Paid)"))">
                <cache-store duration="3600" />
            </when>
        </choose>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally cache values using control flow policies
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose

All you need to do is to put the cache store inside the choose/When policy
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#policy-statement-1

Comment: Thanks for the info! Thats exactly what I was after. Can you check my updated question to see if you have any more ideas? Unfortunately the response body is now blank :(

Comment: Solved by setting `preserveContent` when reading `context.Response.Body` like this  `context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true)` -- more on this in my full answer I shared for completeness

Comment: Yes, preserveContent will resolve your issue. Be careful of using it everywhere as it may cause performance issues due to buffering the whole response payload in the memory.